# how to clone a live site on prestashop (1.7.6.5) to wampserver?

Tags: prestashop, wamp, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to clone a live site from prestashop to local on wampserver but it doesn't work. I followed a lot of tuto but it just doesn't work
(error 404)

PS: I have the code and the sql
PPS: I have a template
PPS: I don't have the .htaccess file
The things that i've tried are:

1. I have tried to connect to my database (and it works)
2. I have changed in the ps_configuration:

   - PS_SHOP_DOMAIN     to "shop1"
   - PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL   to  "shop1"
3. PS_SSL_ENABLED       "1" => "0"
4. and in ps_shop_url, i have changed the domain and domain ssl to "localhost" and the psysical_uri to "/shop1/"  => error 404 in http://localhost/shop1
5. if in ps_shop_url, i change the domain and domain ssl to "shop1" and the psysical_uri to "/"  => error 500 in http://shop1/module/kbprivateshop/login
6. I have also configured my wampserver on the same configuration of the live site
   PHP 7.3.33, MAriaDB 10.5.20
7. I have also deleted the cache in "C:\wamp64\www\prestashop_test\var\cache".

Comment: "it just doesn't work"  doesn't offer much context to be able to help you, you should tell us if you have any errors in your webserver logs or what's going on...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: actually I have an 404 error @user3256843

Comment: ok so i've succeded to clone the site on wampserver. The reason is because of the .htaccess file where i added a "RewriteBase /" under "RewriteEngine on".
But it seems that I now have new problems where the server seems to have some difficulty in reaching a connection with the addons.

Comment: Images doesn't show up on the page: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://shop1/themes/leo_smitten/modules/appagebuilder/views/css/slick.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: remove the .htaccess file located in the main directory of your webshop `/yourwebshop/.htaccess`